# ArcGIS Pro - reset to default (reset profile)

Tags: arcgis-pro, default

Is anyone aware how one can set ArcGIS Pro back to default settings?
In ArcMap etc it was done by following this [tutorial](https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile)

Comment: Can you give an example of something you'd want to "Reset"? As Pro is project based, things like your folder/db connections, etc are saved at the project level, thus they're "reset" with every new project.

Comment: For example:where is saved something like dark theme (where is file containing value that switches it from bright to dark)? Something like xml, cfg file.

Comment: That particular setting is in the registry. `(Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\ArcGISPro\Settings\Theme)` - to the best of my knowledge, most of the things that arent saved as part of the project itself would be in the registry. Of course there could be some exceptions to that, but I don't have a list of what and where.